# Why with select data-native-menu="false" options are not showing?

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, select-menu

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.0 and I have the following code for the select menu. When I use data-native-menu="false" the options are not showing up. Without data-native-menu="false" the options visible to the user.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
            <label for="virtuemart_product_id_box" class="select"> Nombre de producto:
            </label> 
            <select id="virtuemart_product_id_box" name="virtuemart_product_id_box"  data-prevent-focus-zoom="true" data-native-menu="false"> 
<option value="">Seleccione un producto</option> 
<option value="84">Fromage Artesano Tres Leches Madurado 425 gr.</option> 
<option value="85">Queso de Cabra Madurado 425 gr.</option> 
<option value="83">Queso de Oveja Madurado 425 gr.</option> 
<option value="86">Queso de Vaca Madurado 425 gr.</option> 
<option value="87">Queso de Vaca Madurado Ahumado 425 gr.</option>
```

On debug the following information is presented:

> Scrolling to target  -99919 of #virtuemart_product_id_box-listbox.

Why is this happening?

I am using this select in a virtuemart view. I use view.html.php to load the select options

```
$options = array();
    $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '', JText::_('Seleccione un producto'));
    foreach($products as $product):
    $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $product->virtuemart_product_id, $product->product_name);
    endforeach;
    if (isset($product_id)){
        $this->lists['products']= JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'virtuemart_product_id_box', 'class="inputbox" onchange="this.form.submit();" data-prevent-focus-zoom="true" data-native-menu="false" ', 'value', 'text', $product_id);
    }
    else {
        $this->lists['products']= JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'virtuemart_product_id_box', 'class="inputbox" onchange="this.form.submit();" data-prevent-focus-zoom="true" data-native-menu="false" ', 'value', 'text',$options[0]);
    }
```

The default.php that renders html

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JHTML::_( 'behavior.modal' );


$document = JFactory::getDocument();
?>


    <form action="<?php JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post">
        <h1 class="title">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCER') .' '.$this->mf_name ?>
        </h1>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="virtuemart_product_id_box" class="select"> <?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_NAME') ?>:
            </label>
            <?php echo $this->lists['products']; ?>
        </div>
</form>
```

I am also using Jtouch template for joomla mobile display.

I found the following scripts on my html:

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var jtouchPageId            = 0;
        var jtouchPageTransition    = 'fade';
        var jtouchHeaderTheme       = 'b';
        var jtouchAdd2HomMessage    = 'Install this web app on your %device: tap %icon and then <strong>Add to Home Screen</strong>.';
        var jtouchShowAppDialog     = true;
        var jtouchPage                  = '';
    </script> 



   <script type="text/javascript">
vmSiteurl = 'http://localhost/seleccionatu/' ;
vmLang = ""
vmCartText = 'fue agregado a su carro' ;
vmCartError = 'Hubo un error al actualizar su carro' ;
loadingImage = '/seleccionatu/components/com_virtuemart/assets/images/facebox/loading.gif' ;
closeImage = '/seleccionatu/components/com_virtuemart/assets/images/facebox/closelabel.png' ; 
Virtuemart.addtocart_popup = '1' ; 
 faceboxHtml = '<div id="facebox" style="display:none;"><div class="popup"><div class="content"></div> <a href="#" class="close"></a></div></div>' 


    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

        SqueezeBox.initialize({});
        SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
            parse: 'rel'
        });
    });
```

Can these scripts cause the popup for the select not to open? Also noticed that the URL is added with #virtuemart_product_id_box-listbox

Comment: Please format your HTML correctly. Tell us where are you using this select? Is it inside a page, dialog box or popup? And if possible show us more HTML then this, it is simply not enough.

Comment: I am using the select inside a page. If there is some more information to help me solve this problem please ask me! I have been for 5 days going crazy with this problem!

Comment: The select is also inside a form <form action="<?php JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post">